# monacaでスライディングメニューとbxsliderのスワイプ操作が干渉してしまう。

Tags: javascript, monaca

monacaでスライディングメニュー機能が付いたアプリを作成しております。
そこにbxsliderをのせているのですが、bxsliderを操作しようとスワイプするとスライディングメニューが一緒に出てきてしまいます。
bxsliderのオプション等いろいろ試してみたのですが、うまくいきません。

スライディングメニューを生かしたままでbxslider上のスワイプ操作だけはスライディングメニューが反応しないようにするにはどうしたらいいでしょうか？

どなたかわかる方ご教授お願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bxslider`の仕組みだけじゃ厳しいんじゃないかなぁ
…と言うのもスワイプ操作時に親のドキュメントごと動いちゃうので
親のドキュメント(`ons-page`)が動くとスライディングメニューが反応します。
対策は2つほどパッと思いつく感じですが、、、

１．スワイプ判定を自分で行う
こちらはややハードルが高いかもしれませんが
タッチイベントを取得するとタッチされたエレメントを取得できます。
そのエレメントの親要素に`bxslider`が存在しなければスライド方向を認識して
`sideMenu.open()`で開いてやれば良いんでないかな？

２．親にスワイプが影響しないライブラリを使用する
例えば`owl-carousel`だと指定要素の配下が動くので親は動きません。
そういうライブラリを使用するか、作るかですね。

Comment: とても参考になりました。
owl-carouselを使用してみようと思います。
ありがとうございました。